# Has a bankai ever been silently activated?

Tags: bleach

To activate a Bankai or its ability, is the user required to perform some verbal command activation?

For example, Ichigo often yells

> Bankai: Tensa Zangetsu

However, I'm pretty sure that I've read some silent activations, but I can't remember for sure.

So has a Bankai ever been activated without a vocal command?

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Can a mute activate a zanpakutou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/51328/1458), as that question asks whether it is possible. And this question asks if a silent activation has ever happened in the series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, it has.

After re-reading the manga, this happens twice. Once when Ichigo fights Ulquiorra for the first time in Las Noches

[image]

[image]

And again in his [fight](https://youtu.be/gr9qc_MNGJ4?t=147) against Grimmjow

[image]

[image]

Comment: actually it happens three times, you skipped the first time when he saved nel from dordoni and then cut his horn of and then cut the snake monster in half.

Answer (score 4):

A *bankai* has never been silently released before.  That is to say, a Soul Reaper has never silently achieved *bankai* in the middle of a fight and continued the battle.

Each *bankai* does have a formal declaration, even if it is a bit more sly than others (such as Kuchiki Byakuya throwing his sword down on some occasions), but there is still the ceremony of declaring it as *bankai* and revealing its name.

Comment: After re-reading the manga, I've found this to be incorrect. See my answer